# Error en inyección de dependencia en constructor

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Symfony y estoy intentando pasar un servicio al constructor de una clase a través de la inyección de dependencias de Symfony pero obtengo el siguiente error.

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Model\Notifications\NewUserNotificationBox::__construct(), 0
> passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\symfony-template\src\Services\Notification\NotificationChooser.php
> on line 17 and exactly 1 expected

El servicio en cuestión es `Twig\Environment`.

Este es el código de la clase donde estoy intentando llamar al servicio en el constructor.

```js
<?php

namespace App\Model\Notifications;

use App\Entity\Notification\NewUserNotification;
use App\Entity\Notification\NotificationInterface;
use Twig\Environment;

class NewUserNotificationBox {

    private Environment $twig;

    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }
    
    public function create(): NotificationInterface
    {
        return new NewUserNotification();
    }

    public function render(NotificationInterface $notification): string
    {
        return $this->twig->render("components/admin_panel/toolbar/notifications/newUserNotification.html.twig", [
            "notification" => $notification
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y esta es la clase desde donde estoy intentando crear un objeto de `NewUserNotificationBox`.

```js
<?php

namespace App\Services\Notification;

use App\Entity\Notification\NotificationInterface;
use App\Model\Notifications\NewUserNotificationBox;
use App\Model\Notifications\UserBlockedNotificationBox;
use Exception;

class NotificationChooser
{
    public function getNotificationsBlock(NotificationInterface $notification)
    {
        $notificationBox = "";

        if (get_class($notification) == "App\Entity\Notification\NewUserNotification") {
            $notificationBox = new NewUserNotificationBox();
        } else if (get_class($notification) == "App\Entity\Notification\UserBlockedNotification") {
            $notificationBox = new UserBlockedNotificationBox();
        } else {
            throw new Exception(get_class($notification) . " doesn't exist in NotificationBuilder::getNotificationsBlock");
        }

        return $notificationBox->render($notification);
    }
}
```

Si ejecuto el comando `php bin/console debug:autowiring twig --all` obtengo la siguiente salida por consola:

> ## Autowirable Types
>
> The following classes & interfaces can be used as type-hints when
> autowiring:  (only showing classes/interfaces matching twig)
>
> Stores the Twig configuration and renders templates.
> Twig\Environment (twig)
>
> UploaderExtension.
> Vich\UploaderBundle\Twig\Extension\UploaderExtension

Es cierto que no le estoy pasando ningún argumento al constructor cuando creo el objeto, pero ¿no debería llamarse al servicio atomáticamente gracias al Autowiring de Symfony?

He intentado definir el servicios específicamente en services.yml pero tampoco ha funcionado.

Por cierto también he limpiado la caché con `php bin/console cache:clear`.

A ver si podéis arrojar un poco de luz al asunto, gracias.

Comment: [De obligada lectura](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html), si quieres implementar DI en Symfony. Dinos si has seguido las directivas ahí indicadas.

Comment: he seguido las directrices de este apartado: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#rendering-a-template-in-services , además he leido los apartados sobre DI de symfony